# How can I import csv file with special characters?

Tags: character-encoding, postgresql

I am trying to import CSV sheet to Postgres database using PG-ADMIN. I am able to import sheet but after importing sheet due to special characters values are changed.

For example:

- Before Importing:  `Indore - INO`
- After importing: `Indore +AC0- INO`
- Expected value: `Indore - INO`

In the above example, `+AC0` is added in place of `-` (dash).

I am using PG-ADMIN with encoding UTF8. The column: team_name is defined with `character varying(300) NOT NULL`.

How can I import exact value or how can we handle special characters while importing?

Comment: Is the dash character an ordinary minus sign in the data that you're importing?

Comment: what import commands did you use? what table definition did you use (for that column)?

Comment: @Kusalananda yes. Its a minus sign with space both side.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I am using PG-ADMIN tool. There is an option to import so using this only.It uses copy command. column: team_name character varying(300) NOT NULL

Comment: You might have an encoding problem with your input file: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50927451/6216002

Comment: Something is copying your utf8 into utf7.

Comment: @Haxiel thanks for the help by sharing the link. It solved my issue. I just changed my sheet's encoding UTF 7 to  UTF-8. Below link is also useful
https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=20619

Comment: @NishantKhandelwal That's great. You can consider adding an answer here with the details, so that it may help future readers.

Comment: steps which solved my problem using Calc.
File -->save as CSV and check to Edit Filter Setting  --> select character-set to UTF-8 -->ok
In my case character-set was UTF-7. In short you need to change character-set of sheet to UTF-8 and save it as CSV